# Showing more rows when uitableviewcell is clicked

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

Is it possible to open up more rows when a cell is clicked?

For example we have a tableview with a country name. When I click it all the cities in this county would be shown below that cell.

Comment: Yes it is possible, alter your datasource and trigger the table view update in any way that works best for you.

Answer (score 0):

As A-Live says, you should alter your datasource so that it includes the cities just below the country.
Then you could either call

```
tableView.reloadData()
```

or, preferably,

```
tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(_ indexPaths: [AnyObject],
       withRowAnimation animation: UITableViewRowAnimation)
```

The last will perform the animation of inserting the items below the country row.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation: